# Back panel display ports on Z800, connecting to VGA monitor

Tags: hp, cable, display, adapter, monitors

I work for a charity, we've received a HP Z800 workstation. Need to connect a 15-pin VGA monitor. However the the back panel has only the following ports (as shown in the two images) connected to display. Can anyone tell me what these ports are called and what the connectors or adapters required to connect the VGA monitor (a Dell one) cable ?

**Workstation :**

On the workstation, 9-pin-port :
[image]

On the workstation, display ports: 
[image]

On the workstation : Individual view :
[image]

On the workstation : Individual view :
[image]

**Monitor :**

For more info, here are the ports on the monitor :
[image]

[image]

Comment: That site is blocked here (and probably other places). Please upload images using the image upload functions here, whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a "DVI to VGA adapter" (search for that term). They are very inexpensive (a few US dollars) and very common, available online and from many local stores.

(you need the very common male DVI to female VGA)

Comment: The second photo is the video card.  It has one DVI output and two DisplayPort outputs.  Monitors with DisplayPort inputs are very rare, but you can get cables that will convert DisplayPort to HDMI.  For a generic VGA monitor, HighTechGeek is correct.   I just gotta say though, I'm a little shocked that someone would give a Z800 to a charity.  Those machines ran about $6000 US when they were new (my workplace bought 2 of them for our CAD designers.)

Comment: @Charles Burge - god forbid someone give something of value to a charity, amirite? /s Sheesh!

Comment: Haha, we are quite a big charity with an elaborate IT setup elsewhere. Just that I am new to this particular DVI stuff. Neways, thank you.

Comment: @HighTechGeek : Added the ports on the monitor end also for clarity. Doesn't it look like I will need a cable with one end VGA-male (going into the female on monitor) and other end being DVI-male ?

Answer (score 1):

The first picture is a serial RS-232 port, not a video port. The second is a video card with a DVI connector and what looks like 2 x displayport adapter (not 100% clear from the picture) - it's possible to get converters from both DVI and DP to 15-pin VGA but your monitor won't just plug in as it stands, you'll need either a converter or a newer monitor.